# FBSDKShareKit video save in the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to make a Facebook share option for the videos makes by the users of my app.

If I get the url of video from `- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info`

It works fine.

But what I want is share a video save on my app, not a video from asset library.

So I have try this :

```
NSURL *videoURL = [[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:_filePath isDirectory:NO];
FBSDKShareVideo *video = [[FBSDKShareVideo alloc] init];
video.videoURL = videoURL;
FBSDKShareVideoContent *content = [[FBSDKShareVideoContent alloc] init];
content.video = video;
[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self
                            withContent:content
                               delegate:self];
```

And it return me this error :

> Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.share Code=2 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorArgumentValueKey=file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/41372B65-5872-4167-89FD-0F94823397B8/Documents/2015-10-07%2009-26-12.mov,
>   com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=Invalid value for
>   videoURL:
>   file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/41372B65-5872-4167-89FD-0F94823397B8/Documents/2015-10-07%2009-26-12.mov,
>   com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorArgumentNameKey=videoURL}

Have you any suggestion that can help me ?

Thanks

Comment: what I understand is that video can't share on facebook and you want to share video on FB. is it right?

Comment: @HardikShekhat Yes, i can share a video only if the url is from asset library, like : assets-library://asset/asset.mov?id=8AE49BC7-D522-4F54-A141-E95D2C5EAE16&ext=mov

Comment: you must use URL from asset library to share video on fb. I have also use like this is my app.

Answer (score 3):

This is working as expected, according to the [documentation of the iOS SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios#videos), it must be an asset URL, a local file URL won't work.

One suggestion, not sure if this is possible with the iOS SDK, is to save your video in the camera roll of the user and let them chose it that way.

Comment: Hey guys I did the exact same thing here. I save the video to the camera roll and retrieve the url of that one. 
But still the error talks about an "Invalid URL".
Any suggestion?